# How to find out if proxy-user is sent to Proxy by TortoiseSVN

Tags: proxy, svn, tortoise-svn

I configured TortoiseSVN to use a servers file with proxy username and password like this:

```
[apache]
http-auth-types = Negotiate;ntlm;basic
http-proxy-host = 130.0.9.165
http-proxy-port = 8080
http-proxy-username = ik\Fabian.Meier
http-proxy-password = ***
```

where [apache] is svn.apache.org. Our IT claims that the username never arrives at the proxy - instead the client IP appears as username.

Is there any way to check whether I *really* send the username to the proxy or if I misconfigured something?

Comment: WIreshark should be able to tell you.

Comment: I tried, but I did not find anything (but actually, I do not exactly know what to look for)